Bounty awarded to the wrong answer
The bounty to Cannot get ProjectContext for Project Online from Sharepoint Office 365 and get a 403 in .NET 8 was awarded to the wrong answer. My answer is the accepted one, and also with the most upvotes. It took me a while to validate it and to write an answer with my own screenshot from my lab.
The answer was posted after the bounty started. The edit that I made to the answer was to give more details after the person edited their question.
I flagged the question for help from a moderator yesterday, but I don't know if it's the right thing to do.

The bounty was manually awarded to that answer, which is within the prerogative of the bounty setter to do, whether or not the answer is right or better or worse than any other answer. There really isn't anything moderators could or should do about that.
Keep trying to answer questions, maybe next time you'll get the bounty.

Thank you Robert for you answer. I'm a bit disappointed but it's ok

@saad good! Better to be disappointed than fuming. Disappointment is to be expected to be honest, it is a direct consequence of having wrong expectations. If there would be a ranking of websites where it is somehow measured how many wrong expectations they breed... Stack Overflow might just be at the very top.

@Gimby When I answered the question I was not expecting to have the chosen answer. I was hopping of course. I did the job, the answer was accepted, and has the +2 Upvote. So according to the rules, the bounty should be given to me. The user attribute the bounty to another answer by mistake, that is also completely wrong.
I think it's not fair, and suggest that the chosen answer is correct. I think that some moderator should have the right to cancel the bounty attribution to let the user fix the mistaken bounty attribution. But if that is the way the SO community works, I bow to the law.

@saad "So according to the rules": There are no rules which force the OP to award the bounty to the highest votes and/or accepted answer. The OP is free to give their bounty to whatever answer they want, even if they might make a mistake in the process.

I agree, I think I learned it the hard way. I still think it's unfair, but again, if it's the law I have no say in it :)

@saad I think it is important to give the OP the freedom to choose which answer they want to award. There can situations in which it makes sense to give the bounty to an answer with less votes than the accepted one. For example if there is a new answers to an old question which already has a good answer with many votes. The new answer might not be better, but the OP might still decide to reward the effort to come up with an alternative solution with a bounty.

@saad The easiest way to avoid disappointment is to ignore bounties. Choose the questions you answers based on how interesting you find them, how much fun searching for a solution will be for you and how much you can learn in the process.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think you didn't understand my problem. I'm Ok with the freedom of choice. And the examples you give don't match the current situation.
We have a an OP that gives the bounty in error and he claim it : "this got fat fingered. If you open a ticket with Stack Overflow we can change it, I hope. I went to 'give' it to you but the page flipped to and it went to the wrong one. And of course you cannot undo it."
I understand that bounties can't be canceled, even if it's awarded by error. And this is why I say it's unfair and that I'm disappointed.

Either the user who awarded the bounty made a mistake or they awarded the bounty to the other answer on purpose.
Anyway, once the bounty is awarded, there is nothing anyone can do to change that. The moderator flag you raised was declined because moderators cannot and shouldn't do anything in such cases.

Probably on purpose, given the bounty reason appears to be "Reward existing answer". Unless of course you mean they simply clicked the award button on the wrong answer? Which seems... well how do you manage that :-)

@Nickistired anything is possible when you are tired ;)

Thank you Dalika. That's not fair but I'll deal with it.

@saad - It most certainly is fair. It was never a guarantee that your answer would be awarded the bounty. I have been on the receiving end of a user who thought they deserved the bounty I offered, only to be told,  it awarding it to their answer was never in the cards and I was always planning not to award it to their answer. They also had a problem with hearing that, not saying the answer that was awarded the bounty was high quality, but it truly is up to the user who offered the bounty to award the bounty.

That is not the case here. User did an error attributing the Bounty. You can see it in the last comment : I went to 'give' it to you but the page flipped to and it went to the wrong one.
This is why I saying it's not fair and that I'm disappointed, it's that even in the eventuality of an error no one (even moderators) can't cancel the bounty attribution. I never said that the bounty is guarantee to me because I answered.
